# select top 1 or get first record using FMDB

Tags: sqlite, fmdb

I am using FMDB and I just want to select a single record using TOP 1 - can you do this using FMDB?  I have Googled and I haven't found this mentioned anywhere - seems like a pretty common usage scenario.

Anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about fmdb, but it seems to use raw/prepared sql statements, so you can use the SQLite documentation:

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html

You can see that it uses `LIMIT 1` (like MySQL) instead of `TOP 1` (like MS SQL)